# How do I find Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I used to go to Maps on the upper Google screen (next to Images). Then I could just enter an address and eventually get right down to street level to see the house or area. But now I can't seem to find the link to Google Maps.

Where is it hidden?

Comment: How about going to http://maps.google.com?

Answer (score 4):

Are you referring to going to [Maps](https://maps.google.com/) from the primary [google.com](https://www.google.com/) site? If so, on the top right side of the page you have a 3x3 square with the rest of the *Apps*. Click on it and you'll find *Maps*. 
[image: Google app selector]

Answer (score 0):

I usually just type [www.maps.google.com](http://www.maps.google.com)